# Who are Brahm Bhatt Brahmins?

Tags: brahmins, ancestry

I want to know more about Brahm Bhatt Brahmins/Pandits. Who are Brahm Bhatt Brahmins? Is there any difference between Bhatt and Bhaat.

Comment: Meanwhile [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barot_(caste)) may be useful.